# JMeter tests fail in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, jmeter, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have created jmeter tests for my azure release pipeline. I have executed the tests local and everything worked fine. Every time the tests get executed from the azure release pipeline, they fail. I got a Jmeter request to get the token for the other requests. When I execute the test local, I get a 200 response, but when the release pipeline executes the test, I get a 400 response.

My request:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDXob.png)

Pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBl0w.png)

Command Line Script:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE2vr.png)

I tried everything but nothing worked. I also dont found any solutions in the internet.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors without description.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means "Bad Request", it means that the request you're sending from Azure is syntactically incorrect and the server cannot accept it.

The test plan you're running in Azure differs somehow from your local test plan. I can think of the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) from Azure execution
2. Configure both local and Azure JMeter instances to save request and response data. It can be done either via [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) responsible for the [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) or by adding a listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and configure what and where to store. Once you execute local and remote tests inspect request details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. It will allow you to see the differences.

   Once you amend your Azure JMeter instance configuration so it would send exaclty the same request as the local one the issue should go away.

Comment: I already used a View Results Tree. In the Results Tree, there aren't any good information that can help me.